# Basecamp API - retrieving hours

Tags: rest, basecamp

I've been asked to look at the creation of a report that will pull time entry data for a list of projects. Give the project name/id, retrieve a sum of all time spent on it, and a sum of the hours from the past week.

But I can't see where in the new API anything that will give me the time entries, at least, the retrieval process is not in the Basecamp documentation.

I've been looking at this page, which describes the API:

https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you can get it from their old API:

https://mystuff.basecamphq.com/projects/#project_id#/time_entries.xml

This will give you the time entries as XML, which is a pain. It also paginates the results. In the header that you get back are two fields, that tell you how many records are there total, and how many pages:

```
var pageCount = headers["X-Pages"];
var recCount = headers["X-Records"];
```

You can process the records that come back as follows:

```
function processRecords(response)
{
    var respObj =
    {
        totalHours: 0,
        thisWeekHours: 0
    }

    var doc = null;

    if (response.getContentText) 
    {
       doc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), true);
    }
    else if (response.getElements) 
    {
       doc = response;
    }
    else 
    {
      var name = typeof response;
      if (response.constructor) name = response.constructor.name;
      throw new Exception("Incompatible type: " + name);
    }

    var root = doc.getElement();

    var records = root.getElements("time-entry");

    if (records.length > 0)
    {
        for (i = 0;i < records.length; i++)
        {
           var hours = Number(records[i].hours.getText());
           var recordDate = records[i].date.getText();
           if (recordDate >= previousSunday && recordDate <= previousSaturday)
           {
               respObj.thisWeekHours = respObj.thisWeekHours + hours; 
           }

           respObj.totalHours = respObj.totalHours + hours;
        }
     }

     return respObj;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What we have seen so far is there is no easy way to get actual time spent on any project.  You can do something simple like time from the day project is created till its closed/deleted.

The bet way we see doing this is looking at each todo-list and then to-dos under it. Find out the cumulative time spent on each to-do under each todo-list for that project and that will be the actual (nearest possible accurate time) time spent on the project.

You can use the API to get this todo level details and that will do the trick.

If someone has better option let us know as well :) We are doing the above as of today.

Comment: No idea why you got down marked. Oh well. See my answer above, there is a way to get the info.